# Codeigniter Controller for work orders

Tags: php, mvc, controller, codeigniter

I'm working on a project and one of my controllers is getting quite large and hard to maintain or add to. I'm having trouble deciding what belongs in the controller and what I can move to the model. What can I change to improve this?

```
class Job_update extends MY_Controller
{

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->load->helper('html');
    $this->load->model('jobs_model');
}
/**
 * Reassigns a tradie to the work order sending appropriate emails out
 * @param int $job_id 
 */
public function reassign_tradie($job_id)
{
    $this->load->model('send_emails_model');
    $this->load->model('tradie_model');
    $this->load->model('notes_model');
    //get tradie ids via get or post
    if ($this->input->get("tradie")) {
        $tradie_id = $this->input->get("tradie");
        $prev_tradie =  $this->input->get("prev_tradie");
    } else {
        $tradie_id = $this->input->post("tradie");
        $prev_tradie = $this->input->post("prev_tradie");
    }

    if ($tradie_id == $prev_tradie) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', "That tradesman is already assigned to this job");
        redirect('job_update/job_id/'.$job_id);
        return;
    }

    //retrieve data for both tradies
    $data = $this->tradie_model->get($tradie_id); //new tradie
    $prev_tradie_data = $this->tradie_model->get($prev_tradie);//prev tradie

    //update the status to pending and set the new tradie
    $this->jobs_model->update($job_id, array(
        "status" => "Pending",
        "tradie" => $tradie_id,
        "job_tradie_response" => 0
    ));

    //add a note to the job documenting the change
    $job_note_message = "Tradesman has been changed from " . $prev_tradie_data->tradie_firstname .
     " to ". $data->tradie_firstname . " Reason: " .  $this->input->post("reason");
    $this->notes_model->insert($job_id, $job_note_message);

    //select the new job data
    $job_data = $this->jobs_model->with_site_location()->with_tradie()->get($job_id);

    //send the tradie an email of the work order
    $tradie_email = $this->jobs_model->build_tradie_email($job_id, $job_data);
    $this->send_emails_model->insert($tradie_email);

    //if the prev tradie didn't decline the job we need to send a cancellation email
    if ($job_data->status != "Declined") {
        $this->load->model('tradie_model');

        $tradie_data = $this->tradie_model->get($prev_tradie);

        $cancelled_email = $this->jobs_model->build_job_cancelled_email($job_id, $tradie_data);
        $this->send_emails_model->insert($cancelled_email);
    }

    //redirect
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', "Tradesman has been successfully changed");
    redirect('job_update/job_id/'.$job_id);
}

/**
 * Resends the work order to the assigned plumber also updates the status to pending
 * @param int $job_id 
 */
public function resend_work_order($job_id)
{
    $this->load->model('notes_model');
    $this->load->model('send_emails_model');
    //updates status of job
    $job_update = array("status" => "Pending", "job_tradie_response" => 0);
    $this->jobs_model->update($job_update, $job_id);

    //Sends email to tradesman
    $job_data = $this->jobs_model->with_site_location()->with_tradie()->get($job_id);
    $result = $this->jobs_model->build_tradie_email($job_id, $job_data);

    $this->send_emails_model->insert($result);

    //addes note to system talking about change
    $data = array(
    'note' => "Job has been resent to the plumber. Status changed to Pending",
    'notes_job_id' => $job_id,
    'datestamp' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
    'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('username')
    );
    $this->notes_model->insert($data);

    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Resent Work Order to '. $job_data->tradie->tradie_firstname);
    redirect('job_update/job_id/'.$job_id);
}

/**
 * Inserts a new note from post data
 * @param int $job_id 
 */
public function job_add_note($job_id)
{
    $this->_add_note($job_id, $this->input->post('job_notes'));

    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Job Note Added Successfully');
    redirect('job_update/job_id/'.$job_id);
}

/**
 * Loads the photos page for a certain job
 * @param int $job_id
 */
public function photos($job_id)
{
    $data = array('job_id' => $job_id);
    $this->load->view('job_photos_view', $data);
}


public function set_flash_for_bookin($job_id)
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Date/Time has been successfully set');
    redirect('job_update/job_id/'.$job_id);
}

/**
 * Saves the work order details (checkboxes, job_description)
 * @param int $job_id 
 */
public function submit_work_order($job_id)
{
    $data = $this->update_checkboxes($job_id); //get all checkbox data
    $this->jobs_model->update($data, $job_id); //save to db
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Work Order Updated Successfully');
    redirect('job_update/job_id/'.$job_id);
}


/**
 * Resends the customer confirmation email
 * @param string (email) $c_email 
 * @param int $job_id 
 */
public function resend_confirmation_email($c_email, $job_id)
{
    $this->load->model('send_emails_model');
    $this->job_update_model->update_send_email(array("email_sent" => 0), urldecode($c_email));

    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Email Successfully Sent');
    redirect('job_update/job_id/'.$job_id);
}

/**
 * Sets the date for a checkbox
 * @param string $post_data 
 * @param date $current_date_in_db 
 * @param bool (0,1) $is_checked 
 * @return date string format YYYY-MM-DD
 */
private function checkbox_helper($post_data, $current_date_in_db, $is_checked) {
    if($post_data == false)
        return "0000-00-00";
    else if($post_data != false && $is_checked === "0")
        return date("Y-m-d");
    else
        return $current_date_in_db;
}

/**
 * returns an array with checkbox data
 * @param int $job_id 
 * @return array 
 */
public function update_checkboxes($job_id) {
    $job_data = $this->jobs_model->get($job_id);

    $current_date = date('Y-m-d');
    $current_time = date('H:i:s');

    //if 1 box is checked if 0 box is not checked
    $data = array(
    'box_customer_called' => ($this->input->post('checkbox1') == false ? '0' : '1'),
    'box_customer_called_date' => $this->checkbox_helper($this->input->post('checkbox1'), $job_data->box_customer_called_date, $job_data->box_customer_called),
    'box_photos_reviewed' => ($this->input->post('checkbox2') == false ? '0' : '1'),
    'box_photos_received_date' => $this->checkbox_helper($this->input->post('checkbox2'), $job_data->box_photos_received_date, $job_data->box_photos_reviewed),
    'box_photos_received' => ($this->input->post('checkbox6') == false ? '0' : '1'),
    'box_photos_received_date' => $this->checkbox_helper($this->input->post('checkbox6'), $job_data->box_photos_received_date, $job_data->box_photos_received),
    'box_completed' => ($this->input->post('checkbox7') == false ? '0' : '1'),
    'box_completed_date' => $this->checkbox_helper($this->input->post('checkbox7'), $job_data->box_completed_date, $job_data->box_completed),
    'box_completion_certificate' => ($this->input->post('checkbox3') == false ? '0' : '1'),
    'box_completion_certificate_date' => $this->checkbox_helper($this->input->post('checkbox3'), $job_data->box_completion_certificate_date, $job_data->box_completion_certificate),
    'box_invoiced' => ($this->input->post('checkbox4') == false ? '0' : '1'),
    'box_invoiced_date' => $this->checkbox_helper($this->input->post('checkbox4'), $job_data->box_invoiced_date, $job_data->box_invoiced),
    'box_warranty' => ($this->input->post('checkbox5') == false ? '0' : '1'),
    'box_warranty_date' => $this->checkbox_helper($this->input->post('checkbox5'), $job_data->box_warranty_date, $job_data->box_warranty),
    'job_description' => $this->input->post('job_description_new'),
    );

    //if the job was completed and is now unticked change the status
    if($job_data->box_completed == 0 && $this->input->post('checkbox7') == "Completed")
        $data['status'] = "Completed";

    if($job_data->box_completed == 1 && $this->input->post('checkbox7') != "Completed")
        $data['status'] = "Accepted";

    return $data;
}

/**
 * Inserts an email into the send que
 * @param string $message 
 * @param string $email 
 * @param string $name 
 * @param string $email_subject 
 */
public function email($message, $email, $name, $email_subject)
{
    $this->load->model('send_emails_model');

    $data = array('message' => $message,
        'email' => $email,
        'name' => $name,
        'email_subject' => $email_subject);

    $this->send_emails_model->insert($data);
}

/**
 * Uploads a photo to the job directotry
 * @param int $job_id 
 */
public function upload_images($job_id)
{

    $name_array = array();

    if (!is_dir('assets/job_photos/'.add_prefix($job_id))) {//create directory is it doesn't exist
        mkdir('./assets/job_photos/'.add_prefix($job_id), 0777, true);
        $dir_exist = false; // dir not exist
    }

    $count = count($_FILES['userfile']['size']);
    foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) {
        for ($s=0; $s<=$count-1; $s++) {
            $_FILES['userfile']['name']=$value['name'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['type']    = $value['type'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['error']       = $value['error'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['size']    = $value['size'][$s];
            $config['upload_path'] = './assets/job_photos/'.add_prefix($job_id).'/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|PNG|JPG|JPEG';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            if (! $this->upload->do_upload()) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $this->upload->display_errors());
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Successully Uploaded');
            }
        }
    }
    redirect(site_url('job_update/job_id/'.$job_id));
}

public function job_id($job_id) 
{
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $this->load->model('tradie_model');
    $this->load->model('send_emails_model');
    $this->load->model('notes_model');

    //gather all data required for display
    $job_data = $this->jobs_model->with_site_location()->with_tradie()->with_job_notes()->get($job_id);

    $all_users['users'] = $this->user_model->select_all_users();
    $tradies['tradies'] = $this->tradie_model->get_all();

    $email = $this->send_emails_model->where('email', $job_data->site_location->tenant_email)->get();


    //if job isn't found job data will be empty so we load a blank page and return
    if (empty($job_data)) {
        $this->headerlib->load_header();
        return;
    }

    //change all 1's to checked for view
    foreach ($job_data as $key => &$value) {
        //filter thourgh all table coloumns to find the boxes coloumns
        if(strpos($key, 'box') !== false && strpos($key, 'date') === false) {
            if($value == 1)
                $value = "checked";
        }
    }

    $data = array_merge((array)$job_data, (array)$all_users, (array)$job_emails, (array)$tradies);

    $this->headerlib->load_header();
    $this->footerlib->load_footer();
    $this->load->view('job_update_view', $data);
}

/**
 * Deletes a job
 * @param int $job_id job_id you wish to delete
 */
public function delete_job($job_id)
{
    $this->load->model('send_emails_model');
    $this->load->model('tradie_model');

    if($this->session->userdata('user_team_id') != 40)
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'You do not have permission to delete this job');
        redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        return;
    }

    $data = $this->jobs_model->with_tradie()->get($job_id);

    $tradie_data = $this->tradie_model->get($data->tradie->tradie_id);

    $cancelled_email = $this->jobs_model->build_job_cancelled_email($job_id, $tradie_data);
    $this->send_emails_model->insert($cancelled_email);

    if ($this->jobs_model->delete($job_id)) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Job has been successfully deleted');
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Something went wrong, contact an administrator');
    }

    redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/184629/revisions) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Models are for data *models*, you shold not be using them to do things like sending emails, you should be using [libraries](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) for that kind of task instead, and have the library insert a record into the model if required.
- Your `$data` array in `update_checkboxes()` should be generated in a model, since you're creating a data model. I would accomplish this by adding a method to the jobs model and passing it the user input, then have it return that array/model, eg `$data = $this->jobs_model->get_data_array($this->input);`
- You shouldn't be assigning things to the `$_FILES` superglobal (or any superglobals) you should pass the required `$values` array to the library directly. Also, your `$config` variables don't change in the loop so why re-assign them on every iteration.
- You could use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to change all the `1s` to `checked`, although that's probably the type of thing that should be done in a model.

Comment: Thanks this will help a lot! Do you think the long functions like `reassign_tradie($job_id)` should be broken up into smaller functions?

Comment: @rtzcoder ideally all functions would be short but by the same token, you shouldn't make your functions overly short just because some convention says you should. controllers are usually the exception. some of the CI controllers we have at my job are extremely long and there's no obvious semantic way to shorten them. I think your method is fine and I can't see an obvious way to shorten it.